# EF Core set connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a database project that's used by other dotnet projects (azure function app and a web app). I want to use **dotnet ef core cli** to work with migrations, but I don't want to keep my connection string in-code (I want to my repo to be public).

Here's my current DbContext:

```
public ChadwickDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options) {}
```

When I run something like:
`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

I get the error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ChadwickDbContext'. For the
>   different patterns supported at design time, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

This worked previously because I had the connection string hard coded like this:

```
public ChadwickDbContext(string connectionString = "<connection string>"): base(GetOptions(connectionString)) {}
```

Is there any way to **set** the connection string via the **cli** or include some sort of environment file like `appsettings.json` in a database-only project?

[Scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) seems to be close to what I want, but that appears to be more of a way to *generate* your context and models (which is already done).

Comment: You can add `connectionstring` in appsettings.json file

Comment: I'm aware of that and that's what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm not sure how to reference that file in dotnet core3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best way to do this is to setup your own json file and register it:

Example:

```
        public ChadwickDbContext(): base(GetOptions()) {}

        private static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
        {

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var connectionString = config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            return options.Options;
        }
```

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "<Connection String>"
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as i know, you need `startup.cs` to initialize services and database connection.But you know better.